# Lookup row values and replace column names in Python

Tags: python, replace, match, lookup

I have two CSV files whose structure is as shown below (converted into excel)

[image]

and
[image]

I would like to get the values from the "TAG" column in the first file and lookup in the second file headers.

1. Firstly, would like to check whether all values in the TAG column can be matched to a column header in the second file or not, and get a list of those values which cannot be matched to a column header.
2. Secondly, where values can be matched to headers, replace headers with the values from the column "Short" from the first file.

What is the easiest way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the first CSV file with Pandas
df1 = pd.read_csv('first_file.csv')
rename_dict = {row.TAG: row.SHORT for row in df1.itertuples()}

# Read the second CSV file in Python with pandas
df2 = pd.read_csv('sec_file.csv')

# Get a list with all matched TAG values in header names
matched = [tag for tag in df1.loc[:, 'TAG'] if tag in df2.columns]

# Replace the header names from TAG with SHORT and overwrite the second file
df2.rename(columns=rename_dict, inplace=True)
df2.to_csv('sec_file.csv')
```